# How to scale and translate together?

Tags: animation, d3.js

I want to scale and translate D3 force graph, both at the same time. E.g. On clicking a button it shoud scale to 400% and then make itself center on the screen. This should all happen with a smooth animation effect.

```js
//animate vis to visible area 
vis.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", "scale(" + someScaleValue + ")" + "center("0,0)");
```

Doing this, scaling works fine, but graph is not centered. It shifts towards right-bottom corner.

```js
vis.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", "scale(" + someScaleValue + ")");
```

Why is scale is getting reset to 100% when I translate it second time.

I also tried using:

```js
vis.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", "scale(" + scaleValue + ")" + "translate(0,0)");`
```

This is not working too. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`center(0,0)` is not a valid transform-definition to be used with `transform`, [as per the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute).

If you want `translate(0, 0)` to take the object to the center of the screen (usually the top-left corner of `vis`), then you might want to set [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) of the outer `svg` element to be: `"-width/2 -height/2 width height"`. This would set the co-ordinate system inside the `svg` element such that the center lies at `(0, 0)`. Alternatively, you can use `translate(width/2, height/2)`.

Also, each time you call `.attr('transform', ...)`, you overwrite the old value of the `transform` attribute. This is the possible reason why you are losing the original scaling on translating. The best solution would be to put the `vis` element inside a `g` which has the scaling in the `transform` attribute which remains constant.